# AES GCM decryption failed while decrypting data encrypted in flutter

Tags: flutter, go, cryptography, aes-gcm

I'm trying to decrypt the data in golang using the in-inbuild [crypto](https://pkg.go.dev/crypto) library, the data is encrypted in flutter/dart using [steel_crypt](https://pub.dev/packages/steel_crypt) library.
The specific message that is thrown by the golang's crypto library is: `panic: cipher: message authentication failed`.

I'm running flutter app on Android amulator **(localhost is: 10.0.2.2)**

> Golang version: go1.17.6 linux/amd64 |
> Flutter version: Flutter 2.8.1 • channel stable |
> Dart version: Dart 2.15.1

**Golang Code**

```golang
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "crypto"
    "crypto/aes"
    "crypto/cipher"
    "crypto/rand"
    "crypto/rsa"
    "crypto/x509"
    "encoding/base64"
    "encoding/json"
    "encoding/pem"
    "errors"
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "net"
)

func Encode(data []byte) string {
    hb := base64.StdEncoding.EncodeToString([]byte(data))
    return hb
}

// Decoding the base string to array of bytes
func Decode(data string) []byte {
    hb, _ := base64.StdEncoding.DecodeString(data)
    return hb
}

// Generating RSA private key
func GenerateRsaPrivateKey(size int) (*rsa.PrivateKey, error) {
    privateKey, err := rsa.GenerateKey(rand.Reader, size)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    return privateKey, nil
}

// Generating RSA public key
func GenerateRsaPublicKey(privateKey *rsa.PrivateKey) rsa.PublicKey {
    return privateKey.PublicKey
}

// This function can be use encrypt a plain text with rsa algorithm
func RsaEncrypt(publicKey rsa.PublicKey, data string) ([]byte, error) {

    encryptedBytes, err := rsa.EncryptPKCS1v15(
        rand.Reader,
        &publicKey,
        []byte(data))
    return encryptedBytes, err

    // encryptedBytes, err := rsa.EncryptOAEP(
    //  sha256.New(),
    //  rand.Reader,
    //  &publicKey,
    //  []byte(data),
    //  nil)
    // return encryptedBytes, err
}

// This function can be use decrypt a encrypted text with rsa algorithm
func RsaDecrypt(privateKey rsa.PrivateKey, data []byte) ([]byte, error) {
    decryptedBytes, err := privateKey.Decrypt(
        nil,
        data,
        &rsa.OAEPOptions{Hash: crypto.SHA256})
    return decryptedBytes, err
}

//  This fucntion is used to dump/serialize the rsa public key
func DumpKey(key *rsa.PublicKey) ([]byte, error) {
    return x509.MarshalPKCS1PublicKey(key), nil
}

// This function is used to load the rsa public key
func LoadKey(byteKey []byte) (*rsa.PublicKey, error) {
    key, err := x509.ParsePKCS1PublicKey(byteKey)
    return key, err
}

// Generate fixed size byte array
func GenerateAesKey(size int) []byte {
    token := make([]byte, size)
    rand.Read(token)
    return token
}

// This fucntion can be used for encrypting a plain text using AES-GCM algorithm
func AesEncryption(key []byte, data string) ([]byte, error) {
    c, err := aes.NewCipher(key)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    gcm, err := cipher.NewGCM(c)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    nonce := make([]byte, gcm.NonceSize())
    if _, err = io.ReadFull(rand.Reader, nonce); err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    cipherText := gcm.Seal(nonce, nonce, []byte(data), nil)
    return cipherText, nil
}

// This fucntion can be used for decrypting the ciphertext encrypted using AES-GCM algorithm
func AesDecryption(key []byte, cipherText []byte, nonce []byte) ([]byte, error) {
    c, err := aes.NewCipher(key)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("1")
        return nil, err
    }
    gcm, err := cipher.NewGCM(c)

    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("2")
        return nil, err
    }

    noncesize := gcm.NonceSize()
    if len(cipherText) < noncesize {
        fmt.Println("3")
        return nil, err
    }

    cipherText = cipherText[noncesize:]

    // nonce, cipherText := cipherText[:noncesize], cipherText[noncesize:]

    plainText, err := gcm.Open(nil, nonce, cipherText, nil)

    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("4", err.Error())
        return nil, err
    }

    return plainText, nil
}

func ParseRsaPublicKeyFromPemStr(pubPEM string) (*rsa.PublicKey, error) {
    block, _ := pem.Decode([]byte(pubPEM))
    if block == nil {
        return nil, errors.New("failed to parse PEM block containing the key")
    }

    pub, err := x509.ParsePKIXPublicKey(block.Bytes)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    switch pub := pub.(type) {
    case *rsa.PublicKey:
        return pub, nil
    default:
        break // fall through
    }
    return nil, errors.New("Key type is not RSA")
}

type trans struct {
    Key string `json:"key"`
}


type creden struct {
    Data  []byte `json:"data"`
    Nonce []byte `json:"nonce"`
}

func startServer() {
    fmt.Println("Starting Server...")
    l, err := net.Listen("tcp", "127.0.0.1:8080")

    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    defer l.Close()

    c, err := l.Accept()

    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    fmt.Println("Client Connected: ", c)

    data, err := bufio.NewReader(c).ReadBytes('\n')

    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    var t trans

    err_ := json.Unmarshal(data, &t)

    if err != nil {
        panic(err_)
    }

    // fmt.Println("Key: ", t.Key)

    publicKey, e := ParseRsaPublicKeyFromPemStr(t.Key)

    if e != nil {
        panic(e)
    }

    // fmt.Println("Success", publicKey)

    var cre creden
    cre.Data = GenerateAesKey(32)
    cre.Nonce = GenerateAesKey(12)

    jsonRes, err := json.Marshal(cre)

    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    cipherText, e_r := RsaEncrypt(*publicKey, string(jsonRes))

    if e_r != nil {
        panic(e_r)
    }

    fmt.Println("cipherText: ", len(cipherText), " | ", cipherText)

    encodedCipherText := Encode(cipherText)

    n, err := c.Write([]byte(encodedCipherText))

    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    fmt.Println("Written back the response. Written Bytes: ", n)

    data2, err2 := bufio.NewReader(c).ReadBytes('\n')

    if err2 != nil {
        panic(err2)
    }

    var t2 trans

    err_2 := json.Unmarshal(data2, &t2)

    if err_2 != nil {
        panic(err_2)
    }

    fmt.Println("recv data: ", t2.Key)

    cipherText2 := Decode(t2.Key)

    fmt.Println("cipherText2: ", cipherText2)

    plainText2, err := AesDecryption(cre.Data, cipherText2, cre.Nonce)

    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    fmt.Println("plainText: ", plainText2)

}

func main() {
    startServer()
}
```

**Flutter Code**

External Libraries:

1. steel_crypt `flutter pub add steel_crypt`.
2. crypton `flutter pub add crypton`.

Just add below function in your flutter project and call it just before returning the `MaterialApp()`. If you call this function below this level it will get executed every time windows refres.

```dart
void connectFunc() async {
  Socket socket = await Socket.connect('10.0.2.2', 8080);
  print(socket);
  print("Connected...");

  // listen to the received data event stream

  RSAKeypair rsaKeypair = RSAKeypair.fromRandom();

  socket.listen((List<int> event) {
    String base64Response = utf8.decode(event);
    // dynamic response = base64.decode(base64Response);

    // print(response.length);
    // print(response.runtimeType);

    try {
      String plainText = rsaKeypair.privateKey.decrypt(base64Response);
      print(plainText);

      dynamic jsonData = jsonDecode(plainText);

      String Key = jsonData["data"];
      String Nonce = jsonData["nonce"];

      var aes = AesCrypt(key: Key, padding: PaddingAES.pkcs7);

      print('AES Symmetric GCM:');
      var crypted = aes.gcm.encrypt(inp: 'words', iv: Nonce); //encrypt
      // print(crypted);
      // print(aes.gcm.decrypt(enc: crypted, iv: Nonce)); //decrypt
      // print('');

      print("send data: " + crypted);

      dynamic dictData = {
        "key": crypted,
      };

      socket.add(utf8.encode(jsonEncode(dictData) + "\n"));
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }

    // dynamic response = jsonDecode(jsonResponse);
    // String key = response["data"];
    // String nonce = response["nonce"];
  });
  // RSAKeypair rsaKeypair = RSAKeypair.fromRandom();

  dynamic dictData = {
    "key": rsaKeypair.publicKey.toFormattedPEM(),
  };

  socket.add(utf8.encode(jsonEncode(dictData) + "\n"));

  // send hello
  // socket.add(utf8.encode('hello from flutter/dart'));

  // return socket;
}
```

Comment: Looks like the encryption code doesn't prepend the nonce to the cipher text.

Answer (score 1):

I have found the solution of the problem.
The solution is that we have to use another library called [cryptography](https://pub.dev/packages/cryptography) to encrypt the data in flutter/dart.
There is no error at golang side ( except some modifications ).

**AesDecrypt** function at the golang side have been modified

```golang
func AesDecryption(key []byte, cipherText []byte, nonce []byte) ([]byte, error) {
    c, err := aes.NewCipher(key)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("1")
        return nil, err
    }
    gcm, err := cipher.NewGCM(c)

    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("2")
        return nil, err
    }

    // noncesize := gcm.NonceSize()
    // if len(cipherText) < noncesize {
    //  fmt.Println("3")
    //  return nil, err
    // }

    // cipherText = cipherText[noncesize:]

    // nonce, cipherText := cipherText[:noncesize], cipherText[noncesize:]

    plainText, err := gcm.Open(nil, nonce, cipherText, nil)

    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("4", err.Error())
        return nil, err
    }

    return plainText, nil
}
```

Now the whole revised startServer function in here:

```golang
func startServer(nonce []byte, key []byte) {
    fmt.Println("Starting Server...")
    l, err := net.Listen("tcp", "127.0.0.1:8080")

    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    defer l.Close()

    c, err := l.Accept()

    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    fmt.Println("Client Connected: ", c)

    data, err := bufio.NewReader(c).ReadBytes('\n')

    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    var t trans

    err_ := json.Unmarshal(data, &t)

    if err != nil {
        panic(err_)
    }

    // fmt.Println("Key: ", t.Key)

    publicKey, e := ParseRsaPublicKeyFromPemStr(t.Key)

    if e != nil {
        panic(e)
    }

    // fmt.Println("Success", publicKey)

    var cre creden
    cre.Data = Encode(key)    //GenerateAesKey(32)
    cre.Nonce = Encode(nonce) //GenerateAesKey(12)

    jsonRes, err := json.Marshal(cre)

    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    cipherText, e_r := RsaEncrypt(*publicKey, string(jsonRes))

    if e_r != nil {
        panic(e_r)
    }

    // fmt.Println("cipherText: ", len(cipherText), " | ", cipherText)

    encodedCipherText := Encode(cipherText)

    n, err := c.Write([]byte(encodedCipherText))

    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    fmt.Println("Written back the response. Written Bytes: ", n)

    data2, err2 := bufio.NewReader(c).ReadBytes('\n')

    if err2 != nil {
        panic(err2)
    }

    var t2 trans

    err_2 := json.Unmarshal(data2, &t2)

    if err_2 != nil {
        panic(err_2)
    }

    fmt.Println("recv data: ", t2.Key)

    cipherText2 := Decode(t2.Key)

    fmt.Println("cipherText2: ", cipherText2)

    plainText2, err := AesDecryption(key, cipherText2, nonce)

    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    fmt.Println("plainText: ", string(plainText2))

}
```

And now the flutter side of solution:
external denepencies: `cryptography: ^2.0.5`

```dart
void connectFunc() async {
  Socket socket = await Socket.connect('10.0.2.2', 8080);
  print(socket);
  print("Connected...");

  // listen to the received data event stream

  RSAKeypair rsaKeypair = RSAKeypair.fromRandom();

  socket.listen((List<int> event) async {
    String base64Response = utf8.decode(event);

    try {
      String plainText = rsaKeypair.privateKey.decrypt(base64Response);

      dynamic jsonData = jsonDecode(plainText);

      String Key = jsonData["data"];
      String Nonce = jsonData["nonce"];

      String message = "Hello World";

      final algorithm = AesGcm.with256bits();

      final secretBox = await algorithm.encrypt(
        message.codeUnits,
        secretKey: SecretKey(base64.decode(jsonData["data"])),
        nonce: base64.decode(jsonData["nonce"]),
      );

      print("key: ${base64.decode(jsonData["data"])}");
      print("nonce: ${base64.decode(jsonData["nonce"])}");
      print("secretBox: ${secretBox.concatenation(nonce: false)}");

      dynamic dictData = {
        "key": base64.encode(secretBox.concatenation(nonce: false)),
      };

      socket.add(utf8.encode(jsonEncode(dictData) + "\n"));
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
  });

  dynamic dictData = {
    "key": rsaKeypair.publicKey.toFormattedPEM(),
  };

  socket.add(utf8.encode(jsonEncode(dictData) + "\n"));
}
```

Comment: Nonce is short for "number used once". You seem to be re-using yours over and over again. [Don't do that.](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/26790/how-bad-it-is-using-the-same-iv-twice-with-aes-gcm)